# spinner shows like dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I am using the spinner and it opens like a dialog. I need spinner to be open like dropdown menu.

Here is the xml file

```
 <Spinner
 android:id="@+id/sp_countrycode_issue_coupon"
 android:layout_width="60dp"
 android:layout_height="40dp"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:background="@drawable/img_small_box_green"
 android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/img_small_box_green"
 android:gravity="right|center"
 android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Here is the code

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.country_code,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_textview);
sp_country_code.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I posted my images bellow like my view and spinner display view. But I need the spinner to be display like the third image

[image: Here is my layout]
[image: Spinner displays in this way]
[image: But I need in this format]

Comment: Which android version are you testing for?

Comment: presently android 4.1. But the same thing also displayed on 2.3 and below versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the information Dropdown spinner that you shown in **Image 3** is applicable from **version 3.0 and above**. For previous versions like **2.2 and 2.3 it will open like dialog**. It will automatically show dropdown in versions above 2.3

Styles will be automatically added if you choose android version 4.0 or above.

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

[image]

Refrence code

```
    severitySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSeverity);
    severityAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.severity_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    severityAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    severitySpinner.setAdapter(severityAdapter);
```

Edit

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="Test"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: Previously my theme is set to android:Theme.Light now I changed it to android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar and I feel no difference but the only one is radiobuttons I can see on the dropdown menu. Currently I am using android 4.1

Comment: have you written this line in your Manifest. See my edit in answer ----  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change in the manifest file thank you soo much

Answer (score 4):

Late but may be useful to other people, you can simply set the spinnerMode to dropdown:

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

Else, if you decided you fancied a change and wanted dialog in the future just change the mode to dialog!

Comment: Not really bro. spinnermode working API level 11 above

Answer (score 2):

in manifest file change theme to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"`
and in xml file set style for spinner  `style="@style/MyDropDownNav"`
and in style file add style.

```
<!-- style the list navigation -->
<style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/bg_popup</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/top_layout</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It is displaying in dropdown but how to get rid of radio buttons.

Comment: I was able to get the dropdown but how to remove the radio buttons on the list items

Answer (score 0):

**Just change the code like this:**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerMenu = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    RegisterActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item, list);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            spinnerMenu
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);

            country.setAdapter(spinnerMenu);
            country.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Comment: Its showing like "R.layout.spinner_textview" instead of "R.layout.spinner_item"

Comment: But I have made for custom spinner text... so you have just put your xml file instead of it....just nothing and get a proper drop down