# Styled Spinner shows dropdown list as dialog

Tags: android, spinner, styling

after styling my spinner, the dropdown list popup like dialogs, 
i tried to set

```
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
```

but the result was like this

[image]

i don't like this shadow .

and when i remove the previous line ; i get this result

[image]

here is my spinner part of style.xml

```
 <style name="MyTheme.SpinnerAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_spinner_background_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item><!--i really don't like the result of this line-->
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown</item>
    </style>
```

the question is **How to get back the default dropdown style**

Comment: I'm sorry, what's your question?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418456/spinner-shows-like-dialog) I think you got same problem ;)

Comment: i saw it before posting , it doesn't help

Comment: [See this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068063/how-to-remove-the-spinner-border) or [this one might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423391/what-property-controls-spinner-dropdown-background) with your first scenario and remove the border. Not sure as I haven't tried but they look promising

Comment: Why do you want dropdown? I really like the dialog to select an option ://

Comment: codeMagic thanks alot your link gave me idea about what i'm looking for ,i mean i didn't know that its name is "Widget.ListView.DropDown

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by adding this

```
  </style>
            <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
                 <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyTheme.MySpinnerStyle</item>   
            </style>
 <style name="MyTheme.MySpinnerStyle"    parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
       <item name="android:itemBackground">#fff</item>
         <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
     </style>
```

**The secret is in ".Holo.light"**